# How to Prove that this Function is Constant?

Tags: calculus, functional-inequalities

> Let be $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and c a positive constant, if $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that:
>
> $$\frac{|h(a)-h(b)|}{a-b}\leq |a-b|^c$$
>
> Prove that $h$ is constant.

I tried to use the definition of derivative or the triangle inequality but I didn't find the solution.

Comment: The limit of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ as $h\to 0$ is 0 by the inequality we have. Thus, $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$. So, the function is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

One approach mentioned above is to show that the derivative exists and is equal to zero. Let's try to do something more elementary.

Note that by assumption $$|h(b)-h(a)|\le |b-a|^{c+1}.$$

Fix a point $x$ and let $n$ be a positive integer. Write $h(x)-h(0)$ as a telescopic sum and take absolute value (first line), then  use triangle inequality (second line), and finally use the assumption, and take limit as $n\to\infty$ (third line):

\begin{align*}  |h(x) - h(0)| &= |\sum_{j=1}^n h(\frac{jx}{n})-h(\frac{(j-1)x}{n}) |\\& \le \sum_{j=1}^n |h(\frac{jx}{n}) - h(\frac{(j-1)x}{n})| \\
& \le n|\frac{1}{n} x|^{c+1}=n^{-c}|x|^{c+1}\underset{n\to\infty}{\to} 0
\end{align*}

Therefore $h(x)=h(0)$ for any $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$\underset{h \to 0}{\lim} \frac{|h(x+h)-h(x)|}{h}$$

We have for all $h >0$: $$ 0 \le \frac{|h(x+h)-h(x)|}{h} \le h^c$$

Thus, we have $$0 \le \underset{h \to 0}{\lim}\frac{|h(x+h)-h(x)|}{h} \le \underset{h \to 0}{\lim} h^c =0$$

It follows by the sandwich/squeeze theorem that $$\underset{h \to 0}{\lim}\frac{|h(x+h)-h(x)|}{h} =0 $$

Hence $h$ is differentiable everywhere, and has derivative of 0 everywhere. It follows that it must be a constant function.

Comment: We don't need to prove the continuity of the function in this case?

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity, so we killed two birds with one stone, so to speak.